# State does not save ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

When creating a component I make a query to an api where I bring a table with information, when passing this information to another component as props, it receives it correctly but I cannot assign it as state

Here I create the component, I make the query

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Table from './table/Table';

class Busqueda extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super (props);
    this.state={
      data:[{}]
    }
  }

  componentWillMount = async()=>{
    const response = await fetch (`http://localhost:4000/autores`);
    const columns=await response.json()
    this.setState({
      data:columns.datos
    });
  }

  render() {    
    return (
        <div>
            <Table data={this.state.data}></Table>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Busqueda;
```

Here I receive the prop but I can't get it to be assigned as a state

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Table extends Component {


  constructor(props){
    super (props);
    this.state={
      data:this.props.data
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.data.map((elemento,i) => (
              <tr key={i}>
                <th scope="row">{elemento.id}</th>
                <td >{elemento.nombre}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Table;
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzQZj.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are assign props once, on init. To listen on that changes you should use componentDidUpdate method.

Or just use props to render table rows. I strongly suggest to rethink dataflow, in my opinion Table should be stateless.